# Node extraction

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I need to extract all information under 'heading' node.

```
<doc:level id="25">
    <heading>
        Some text... 
        <italic>Italic text</italic>
    </heading>
```

If I use:
//doc:level/heading/text()
it returns only "Some text... "

If I use:
//doc:level/heading
it returns only "Some text... Italic text" without node "italic", but I need this node in the result.

How could I get the result:

```
"Some text... <italic>Italic text</italic>"
```

Comment: So how exactly do you use XPath, which API or which tool do you use that "returns" those results? The path `//doc:level/heading` should select the `heading` element.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to extract all information under 'heading' node.

Try:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="/doc:level/heading/node()"/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use it. I have to use only XPath

Comment: @Smile The XPath expression is `/doc:level/heading/node()`. Why is your question tagged `xslt`?